# How to prevent CONCAT function adding space in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, string, concat

Postgresql-11

```
select tick_time, nano_secs,
    concat( to_char(tick_time, 'MMDD HH24:MI:SS.US'),
            to_char(nano_secs, '000') )
from ticks
order by tick_time, nano_secs limit 100;
```

I want to concat 2 strings like above, but it always add a space char between the two strings.

How to prevent it doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not `concat()` it's the `to_char()` when formatting the integer value. Use the `FM` modifier to get rid of the spaces:

```
to_char(nano_secs, 'FM000')
```

Comment: Got it, Thank you!